# Remove unnecessary page before go to mainpage

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I need to go to mainpage directly if user was logged in the codes was fine, here's part of my codes:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('mainpage', {
        url: '/mainpage',
        onEnter:function($state){
            // Anything you can think of
            //Check if user already logged in
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
                if (!user)
                 {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            });
        },
        templateUrl: 'modules/mainpage/mainpage.html',
        controller: 'mainpageCtrl',
        module:'mainpage'
    })
```

But before my `mainpage` loaded, there's a page appeared suddenly like below:

[image]

How to avoid this uncalled page? I checked there is no `$ionicLoading.hide` used. Can you suggest me the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: whats in your $urlRouterProvider.otherwise

Comment: go to mainpage.

Comment: Since you use it on OnEnter event, it will not load unless your auth resolves. Do you have a splashscreen that you can use and put the auth inside the controller of the mainpage and once auth is resolved, close the splashscreen

Comment: I just use default splash screen provided by ionic..is it possible?

Comment: does ionic has any before enter events?

Comment: Yes, it does $scope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function( scopes, states ) {})

Comment: ok..I want to try first. thanks for your response

Comment: Still not working.. @SouravDas

Comment: Can you increase the splashscreen duration in config.xml

Comment: Is it the best solution since I tried to avoid the manual timeout before it comes @SouravDas